# UILabel with iOS Storyboard: I can set the text explicitly, but introduce stringWithFormat: can't set text

Tags: nsstring, storyboard, uilabel, custom-cell, stringwithformat

This is a weird one.  I've got a label on my storyboard in a custom prototype cell whose tag is 102.  As the subject title suggests, I can set the text of the label in various ways and it appears on the device as expected.  Here are the methods I've tried that work:

```
nameLabel.text = @"My buddy's name";
nameLabel.text = [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"];
[nameLabel setText:[[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
```

These, however, don't work...

```
NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
[nameLabel setText:nameString];
```

also...

```
[nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]]];
```

and...

```
nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
```

I need for the cells to read:  "game with so-and-so" where "so-and-so" is the opponent's name, obviously.  Any ideas as to what would cause this?

EDIT:  So here's some more code, demonstrating how I'm attacking this thing:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MatchCell"];
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    ...
}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    nameLabel.text = [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"];
    [nameLabel setText:[[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
    NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
    [nameLabel setText:nameString];
    [nameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]]];
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"game with %@", [[self.matchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"player2Username"]];
}
        return cell;
}
```

I'm using Parse as my BaaS.  There really doesn't seem to be a problem there, as I can retrieve, log, and display on my iPhone (in the cell) the player's username and any other data I want, as long as I don't incorporate stringWithFormat:.

I tried cleaning the project and the build folder, uninstalling from the device, etc.  Re-ran it.  Still no luck.

Comment: how are you getting your label?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, ManicMonkOnMac.  I dragged the label into my cell prototype from the object library.  I assigned the tag in attributes inspector.  I'm trying to assign the string to the label from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  The string data itself--there doesn't seem to be a problem here, as I can log what I want and even get the username into the cell on the device AS LONG AS I DON'T USE stringWithFormat:--is retrieved from my back-end service's servers.  Seems stringWithFormat: is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Newb mistake.  I didn't size the UILabel wide enough to accommodate the extra text.  That is to say I could explicitly set a string (e.g. nameLabel.text = @"player name";) and there was enough room to fit the player's name, but whenever I tried to prepend "game with " to any user's name, it had the effect of making the entire string too long for the small width of the UILabel to accommodate.  So, I guess it was reverting to the text of the label (which I had set in Interface Builder/Storyboard), "game with...".

In a nutshell, be sure you make your UILabels wide enough to accommodate the text they're going to be handling, kids!  If you don't, someone's gonna wind up with a disease or pregnant or worse.  I've seen it a thousand times.